# How do I get a single line per customer including the first line of an order in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables - Customers, and Orders.  Each Customer will have 1..n Orders.  They have a relation on a Foreign Key to the Customers table in the Orders table.  So far, so DB 101.

I need a query that will return a single row per Customer, together with the date and Order ID of that customer's latest order.  ALL Customers have at least one order.  I can easily do this with a function, but I'd prefer to do it in SQL.

Comment: Look into the `JOIN` [manual](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: I would however - in your case - create a third table. `customer_orders`. In this table you would link the **customer_id** with the different **order_ids**. Each record presents a link to an order in the orders table. This makes it much easier to do such things . A good explanation can be found [here](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/)
This technique is called **normalization**

Comment: The proposed customer_orders table would be required if an order could belong to more than 1 customer.  Since there's a 1..n relation between Customer and Orders, the FKCustomerID key in the Orders table suffices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of auto incremented ID-s, and no variance with dates, the solution is that simple:

```
SELECT c.*, o.*
FROM Customer c 
JOIN (SELECT max(id) as order_id, customer_id 
      FROM Order GROUP BY curtomer_id) conn on c.id = conn.customer_id
JOIN Order o on o.id = conn.order_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state your DBMS, so I'm assuming an ANSI compliant engine.

```
select *
from (
    SELECT c.*, 
           o.*, 
           row_number() over (partition by o.customer_id order by order_date desc) as rn
    FROM Customer c 
      JOIN Order o on o.customer_id = c.id
)
where rn = 1
```